# How do I change cursor key behaviour in the command line in neovim?

Tags: vim, zsh, putty, tmux, neovim

Currently, when I press cursor-left in the command line in neovim (:whatever foo bar), the cursor will move over a whole word. Most of the time, I just want it to move one character.

Answer (score 1):

This shouldn't be the default behaviour. It's probably a plugin or something you once added to your vimrc at some point. Try using `:verbose cmap` to see what it's set to (also see [How do I debug my vimrc file?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/51)).

You should also be able to use `:cnoremap <Left> <Left>` to restore the default behaviour.

Comment: (Edit, <ENTER> does post here...)

This is distinctly odd.

It happens outside of tmux, even if I use bash instead of zsh, even with nvim -u NORC, even after moving .vim/plugins away. There is no mapping to be found, and your cnoremap doesn't change anything either.

I have absolutely no clue.

It's a bit sad, really, since it's the only thing that keeps me from `alias vi=nvim`

Comment: I found the solution. Will put it here as an answer so others can find it. Anyway. your comment made me re-evaluate the thing, so thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with `putty` and how it sends cursor keys. The trick is to find out what nvim actually sees, and then `:cnoremap...` accordingly.

The way to figure out what your nvim receives, is this:

- enter input mode
- hit ctrl-v
- hit the key you want to see

Be aware that nvim behaves slightly differently than vim here: vim shows you the actual escape sequence, while nvim shows you the translated keys. The latter is a tad unfortunate.

In my case, for reasons I haven't figured out, nvim saw Ctrl-Left as , but Left as . Since I never need S-Left in the command line, `:cnoremap <S-Left> <Left>` did the trick.